# toggle button, the menu does not toggle

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem with the toggle button. When I click the toggle button. The menu is still displayed... I would like to make it disappear, but I don't know how to make the menu disappear after clicking. But,I don't know how to make the menu disappear after clicking?

I share some screenshots with you.

**Here is the page**

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roIRh.png)

**When the user clicks on the toogle button**

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU4S9.png)

**The menu is always displayed**

[img3e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgjPM.png)

The code is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bvzywr?file=src/styles.css).

Thanks in advance for your help and time to my problem.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    background-color: #2af598;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana, Tahoma;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
}


/* MENU - SIDEBAR */


/* C'est le fond bleu vertical */

.sidebar {
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*#239cd3;*/
    height: 781px;
}


/* C'est le logo */

.sidebar .logo-details {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


/* Centraliser les rubriques */

.sidebar .menu {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 45px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/* Ajustage icones  */

.sidebar li i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.2rem;
    left: 1rem;
    color: #595959;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/* Placer les flèches à droite */

.sidebar li i.fa-chevron-down {
    right: 1rem;
    left: auto;
}


/* Pivoter en haut / en bas la flèche */

.sidebar li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/* Changement de couleur de la rubrique après clique */

.sidebar li.active .menu {
    color: #b63b4d;
}


/* Changement de couleur icones après clique */

.sidebar li.active i {
    color: #b63b4d;
}


/* Adaptation fond pour le sous menu */

.submenu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    /* #239cd3;*/
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: height 0.4s ease;
}


/* Ligne de séparateur sur chaque submenu */

.submenu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}


/* Sous-menu après cliquage */

.submenu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    padding: 12px;
    padding-left: 42px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}


/* Survole submenu en couleur */

.submenu a:hover {
    background: #b63b4d;
    color: #fff;
}


/* Header */


/* Bandeau blanc */

.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    left: 320px;
    width: calc(100% - 320px);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}


/* le toogle */

.header .header-button i {
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 500;
}


/* le titre du header */

.header .header-title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 35px;
}


/* le header écrasse le sidebar */

.sidebar.active~.header {
    left: 0px;
    width: calc(100% - 0px);
}


/* menu déroulant après avoir activé le toogle  */

.sidebar.active {
    width: 60px;
}

.selected {
    background: #05aed6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{ active: showSideBar }">
    <div class="logo-details"> </div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.active]="menu.active">
            <ng-container>
                <div class="menu" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
                    <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i> {{ menu.name }}
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>
                <ul class="submenu" #submenu [ngStyle]="{ 'height': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight + 'px' : 0 + 'px' }">
                    <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
                        <a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }}"> {{ submenu.name }} </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="header">

    <div class="header-button">
        <i class="bx bx-menu" (click)="toggleSideBar()"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header-title">Bonjour</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I us Angular material maybe that can help you

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

In your html:

```
Header

<button (click)="toggle()">  
     menu
</button>
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav style="width: 15%" [opened]="open" [mode]="'side'">
    List des liens 
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="height: 90vh">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

Footer
```

In your  .ts

```
.....

open = false

toggle(){
   This.open=!open;
}

......
```